# Closed form of $\frac1s\int_0^\infty e^{-s(\tanh(t)+at)}dt=\frac1s\int_0^1e^{-st}(1-t)^{\frac{as}2-1}(1+t)^{-\frac{as}2-1}dt$ to invert $\tanh(x)+ax$?

Tags: laplace-transform, closed-form, hypergeometric-function, hyperbolic-functions, inverse-laplace

$\def\L{\operatorname L} \def\M{\operatorname M} $
Our goal is inverting $f(x)=\tanh(x)+ax$ via [Laplace inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform). The Laplace transform of $h(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ is:

$$\L_s(h(t))=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}h(t)dt\mathop=^{h(t)\to t}\int_0^\infty t e^{-s f(t)} df(t)=\frac1s\int_0^\infty e^{-s(\tanh(t)+at)}dt\mathop=^{\tanh(t)\to t}\frac1s\int_0^1e^{-st}(1-t)^{\frac{as}2-1}(1+t)^{-\frac{as}2-1}dt \tag1$$

This integral matches the [Whittaker M function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.16) integral representation:

> $$\frac{\Gamma\left(u-k+\frac12\right) \Gamma\left(u+k+\frac12\right)}{(2u)!z^{u+\frac12}2^{-2u}}\M_{k,u}(z)=\int_{-1}^1 e^\frac{zt}2 (1+t)^{u-k-\frac12}(1-t)^{u+k-\frac12}$$

but the bounds are different. A [bilateral Laplace transform](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=bilateral+laplace+transform) gives $\int_{-1}^1$ bounds after using the same substitutions, but the resulting integral may diverge. The similar [$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-x\tan t+\alpha t} \;dt $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163742/to-find-closed-form-of-int-0-frac-pi2-e-x-tan-t-alpha-t-dt) almost certainly does not have a closed form with the [confluent hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/), of which Whittaker M function is one. [Humbert series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series):

> $$\Phi_1(a,b,c;x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}\int_0^1 e^{yt}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1}(1-xt)^{-b}dt$$

would work, but it is a last resort. Also, as implied by [“Conditions to apply the inverse Laplace transform”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751713/conditions-to-apply-the-inverse-laplace-transform), $\L_s(h(t))$ is finite, so the inverse Laplace transform converges. Thus we likely have an integral representation for $f^{-1}(x)$ if $(1)$ is evaluated.

Does $(1)$ have a simpler closed form than with the Humbert series?

Comment: If you make the substitution $u=\frac{1}{2}-t$, you can transform your integral into the one you give for the Whittaker M function.

Comment: Could  you explain how: $\int_0^\infty t e^{-s f(t)} df(t)=\frac1s\int_0^\infty e^{-sf(t))}dt$ ?

Comment: For example ,inverting $f(x)=x^2+x$ using `Laplace inversion` can we find all solution ? I only get: $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 t+1}-\frac{1}{2}$, but exist another solution: $-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 t+1}-\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: But if I want invert for example: $f(x)=x^6+x$ can be done?To find  all solution ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk It would be a good idea to ask a question about this. Maybe substitute $x=e^{\frac{\pi i n}3}\sqrt[6]w$ to get an equation for the $n$th solution. I am not sure how to effectively apply the (inverse) Laplace, or maybe [Mellin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem), transform afterwards.

Comment: @TymaGaidash What do you mean incorrectly converges? I find that it converges when $a>0$ and $s>0$ just as expected.

Comment: @Andrew The Whittaker M function integral representation does [not match $(1)$, as seen in this edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4733033/edit/98bc9ffc-c67f-426d-b8fe-10f91eb960ac), and therefore incorrectly converges. The comment you refer to did not say $(1)$ diverged

Comment: Apologies, incorrectly converges is not terminology I've heard before. That edit also seems to be different than the version I responded to which had a $\frac{3}{2}-t$, and  $\frac{1}{2}+t$ in the terms.

Comment: @Andrew [This integral representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.16) is more convenient to use, so it replaced the one in the original  question and it was mistaken to “plug in $k=\frac{as}2,z=-2s,u=-\frac12$“, in the second edit, as the integration bounds are different hence the third edit. As for the terminology, maybe “does not equal” would have been better to use.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully someone will find a simpler function than the [Humbert series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series), but expanding with $e^y$’s Maclaurin series, the [Gauss hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), and the [Pochhammer symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) gives: $$\frac1s\int_0^1e^{-st}(1-t)^{\frac{as}2-1}(1+t)^{-\frac{as}2-1} dt=\frac2{as^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1)_n(-s)^n\,_2\text F_1\left(n+1,\frac{as}2+1;n+\frac{as}2+1;-1\right)}{\left(\frac{as}2+1\right)_nn!}$$

whereas

> $$\Phi_1(a,b,c;x,y)=\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_{m+n}(b)_m}{(c)_{m+n}m!n!}x^m y^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_n y^n\,_2\text F_1(a+n,b;n+c;x)}{(c)_nn!}$$

The $\Phi_1$ integral representation, from the question, or single sum definition analytically continues the double sum outside $|x|,|y|<1$. Therefore:

$$\boxed{f(x)=\tanh(x)+ax\implies f^{-1}(x)=\frac1{\pi ia}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s^2}\Phi_1\left(1,\frac{as}2+1,\frac{as}2+1;-1,-s\right)ds}$$

The Mathematica code

`InverseLaplaceTransform[Sum[((-s)^n Gamma[(a* s)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[1 + n, 1 + (a *s)/2, 1 + n + (a*s)/2, -1])/(s Gamma[1/2 (2 + 2 n + a *s)]),{n,0,b}],s,x]`

for $b\to\infty$ and certain $a,x$ confirms this:

[image]