# Mellin transform of Inverse function.

Tags: integration, inverse-function, mellin-transform

Mellin transform of $h(t)=f^{-1}(t)$ is:

$$M_s(h(t))=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}h(t)dt\mathop=^{h(t)\to t}\int_0^\infty t f(t)^{s-1} df(t)=?$$

Could someone go through a step-by-step.

First part:

Using: $$h(t)=f^{-1}(t)$$ substituting: $u=f^{-1}(t)$ ->$f(u)=t$-> $df(u)=dt$

$$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}h(t)dt=\\\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}f^{-1}(t)dt=\\\int_0^\infty f(u)^{s-1}f^{-1}(f(u))df(u)=\\\int_0^\infty f(u)^{s-1}u df(u)=\\\int_0^\infty tf(t)^{s-1}df(t)=?$$

Second part:

Assuming that $f$ is continuous and of local finite variation on $[0,\infty)$,

$$d_t(f(t)^{s-1})=(s-1)f(t)^{-1} f(t)^{s-1}df(t)$$

Integration by parts yields

$$\int_0^\infty tf(t)^{s-1}df(t)=\frac{1}{s-1}\int^\infty_0t f(t) d_t(f(t)^{s-1})=?
$$

Similar question may find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737111/laplace-transform-of-inverse-function),I can't integrate by parts.

Thanks.

Comment: It appears you have too many variables in your Mellin transform ($x$ should be $t$).

Comment: @TymaGaidash The Mellin transform only converges for $-1<\Re(s)<-\frac{1}{6}$, so I don't believe you can integrate along the line $s=0.2+i t$.

Comment: @StevenClark Thanks. This clears up the convergence. The integral now works with $\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty},-1<c<-\frac16$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function with points $(0,0)$ and $(\infty,\infty)$ will probably not work with the [Mellin inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem), but could with the [Ramanujan master theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem), say if $s=-n,n\in\Bbb N$. If the function has these points and $\lim\limits_{t\to0}t\ f(t)^s=0$, then the [DI method](https://arnoldfw.com/pdf/di_method.pdf) yields:

$$\begin{matrix}&\text D&\text I\\+&t&f(t)^{s-1}f’(t)\\-&1&\frac1s f(t)^s\end{matrix}$$

and since $\lim\limits_{t\to0}t\ f(t)^s=0$:

$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^\infty t\,f(t)^{s-1}f’(t)dt=\left.\left(\frac tsf(t)^s\right)\right|_0^\infty-\frac1s\int_0^\infty f(t)^sdt=\frac1s\int_0^\infty f(t)^sdt\end{aligned}$$