# Does any closed form of this integral exists or is related to some special function integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, special-functions

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i \omega x-i b \tanh( x)}dx$$

I have to solve this integral for my research project .I substituted $ \tanh{x} = y $ and $ \tanh^{-1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}\log{\frac{1+y}{1-y}} $, and finally got the integral

$$
\int_{-1}^{+1} dy \, (1+y)^{\frac{\iota \omega}{2}-1} \, (1-y)^{\frac{-\iota \omega}{2}-1} \, e^{-\iota \omega y}
$$

where $ \omega $ is the frequency and is positive and continuous.

and then   here we have  [Closed form of $\frac1s\int_0^\infty e^{-s(\tanh(t)+at)}dt=\frac1s\int_0^1e^{-st}(1-t)^{\frac{as}2-1}(1+t)^{-\frac{as}2-1}dt$ to invert $\tanh(x)+ax$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733033/here) . My question is does this provide answer to my question .

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your integral is essentially the [Whittaker M function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.16). The edits were supposed to merge, but they did not for some reason. Sorry, but previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867378/solve-int-infty-infty-ei-a-x-i-b-tanh-frac-xbdx-frac1-pi-int-0-i?noredirect=1#comment10378352_4867378)

Comment: i have imaginary weight in the integral and here https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.16   is not . so my question is will the argument of whittaker function be complex . i'm new to this site . please forgive for  not linking the details .